Automatically create a new table every month
I would like to create a new table based on the active table and name it after cell A1 (e.g.: "June"). Addition: Ideally automatically after each month.
Thanks a lot
Stefan
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2:C3').activate();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('June');
};


Could you show us your attempts and clarify what you mean by "specific name"?

How to get name of a range or cell that has a name.  If a cell has a name then it must be a named range. Here's an example of cell A2 in Sheet0
function getNameOfCell(cell = "Sheet0!A2") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const name = ss.getNamedRanges().reduce((a,nr,i) => {
    let ra1 = nr.getRange().getA1Notation();
    let na1 = nr.getRange().getSheet().getName();
    let t = `${na1}!${ra1}`
    if(t == cell) {
      a = nr.getName();
    } 
    return a;
  },'')
  Logger.log(name)
}

Execution log
8:44:52 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:44:45 AM  Info    ThisIsIt
8:44:54 AM  Notice  Execution completed

my named ranges

According to your question you said  you know how to do everything else so this should be enough to get you started.

Hey Cooper, thanks for now. I updated my topic to be more specific.

Your question is a little short on details
